# Error: too few arguments in function call, when using a constant

Tags: c

I defined the following constant:

```
#define SIZE 1;
```

And then used it as follows:

```
foo = calloc(SIZE, sizeof(char));
```

Why do I get this:

> Error: too few arguments in function call

Comment: Remove the `;` in the macro definition.

Answer (score 4):

Lose the `;` in the `#define`. That's expanding to:

```
foo = calloc(1;, sizeof(char));
```